# Form tag properties being set outside the Master Page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a master page in an MVC project that contains the opening tag for the form:

```
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

but when I open a view and go to 'View Source' I get this:

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="1104" id="form1">
```

There are a lot of asp controls in the view which I want to replace with helpers or basic html and have the 'action' property point to an action in my controller.

I've searched the code for 'form1'(including javascript files) and can't see where the method and action (which is a userid that I want to point to an action in my controller) are being set.

I know it's difficult for anyone to answer without looking at the project as a whole but I'm not expecting that.  I'm just looking for ideas which might put me in the right direction.

thanks

Comment: Why is it `runat="server"` for an mvc page?

Comment: That's another issue that I need to take care of but it's not relevent to this particular issue.  The problem is it's being changed from what is in the master page and I don't know where or what is changing it.